# Wordpress get most popular posts in current post category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to get the top 3 most popular posts on the bottom of all my posts. Which I've achieved. But I really need to display the top 3 most popular within the current post's main category.

I've used

```
<?php $popular = new WP_Query(array(
         'posts_per_page'=>3, 
         'meta_key'=>'popular_posts', 
         'orderby'=>'meta_value_num', 
         'order'=>'DESC'
         ));
```

to get most popular. But when I add in categories, it returns nothing:

```
<?php $popular = new WP_Query(array( 
         'posts_per_page'=>3, 
         'cat' => 60, 
         'meta_key'=>'popular_posts', 
         'orderby'=>'meta_value_num', 
         'order'=>'DESC'));
```

I've searched and searched for this and I've come close but I suspect my php skills are woefully short! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of your cat=>60 trying to use category=>60

Comment: Thanks for the response! Changing to category=>60 means that my query returns results again but not results in my category. Just the 3 most popular posts regardless of category :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to match the category try this:

```
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => '3',
     'meta_key'=>'popular_posts', 
     'orderby'=>'meta_value_num', 
     'order'=>'DESC',
     'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => array ( 60 ) //you can add more comma separated category ids here
                        )
                    )
                );
$popular = new WP_Query( $args );
if (  $popular->have_posts() ) :
     while ( $popular->have_posts() ) : $popular->the_post(); 
          echo '<div class="entry-content">';
          echo '<h2 class="entry-title main_title">'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
          the_content();
          echo '</div><!-- .entry-content -->';
     endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm sorry for the newb response, but... I can't get this to work. I'm doing this:

$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($arr_posts->have_posts()) : $arr_posts->the_post(); ?>
STUFF HERE
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

My feeling is that I'm doing something really stupid - but what?!!

Comment: Thanks for editing, I really appreciate your time :)
I can't get the query to work, it breaks every time. I tried taking out the whole tax_query part and that unbreaks it.

Comment: sorry, I forgot a comma after 'DESC', try again with the comma

Comment: It worked. You're awesome. Thank you! Apparently I can't upvote or anything else due to my complete newb status :)